# Strange Spring Transaction Behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm having a difficult time understanding Spring Transactions. First off, I am trying to use as little of Spring as possible. Basically, I want to use @Transactional and some of its injection capabilities with JPA/Hibernate. My transactional usage is in my service layer. I try to keep them out of test cases. I use CTW and am spring-configured. I have component scan on the root of my packages right now. I also am using Java configuration for my datasource, JpaTransactionManager, and EntityManagerFactory. My configuration for the JpaTransactionFactory uses:

```
        AnnotationTransactionAspect.aspectOf().setTransactionManager( txnMgr );
```

I do not use @EnableTransactionManagement.

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time understanding the rules for @Transactional and can't find an easy page that describes them simply. Especially with regards to Session usage. For example, what if I want to use @Transactional on a class that does not have a default no-arg constructor?

The weirdest problem I'm having is that in some of the POJO service classes Transacitonal works great while in others I can see the transactions being created but operations ultimately fall saying that there is "no session or the session has been closed". I apologize for not having code to reproduce this, I can't get it down to a small set. This is why I am looking for the best resources so I can figure it out myself.

For example, I can have a method that gets a lazily fetched collection of children, iterates through it and puts it into a Set and returns that set. In one class it will work fine while in another class also marked with @Transactional it will fail while trying to iterate through the PersistentSet saying that there is no session (even though there IS a transaction).

Maybe this is because I create both of these service objects in a test case and the first one is somehow hijacking the session?

By the way, I have read through the spring source transaction documents. I'm looking for a clear set of rules and tips for debugging issues like this. Thanks.

Comment: Spring has three ways of instrumenting classes: DynamicProxy (interfaces only), cglib or AspectJ. . . It will default to cglib if you're not using AspectJ weaving, and you want to add transaction annotations to a normal class (not an interfac). cglib requires a default ctor.

Comment: I should also note that the transaction management seems to work well everywhere. This place where it throws the no session exception is where it needs to perform lazy loading. I'm loading a one to many collection into another collection. It is all contained in an @Transactional method so there SHOULD be an active session. I only return the populated HashSet. Basically, this is going on within a Transactional method "return new HashSet<>( parent.getChildren() );". Not sure what happened to the session. I'll see if I can create a small reproducible test.

Comment: @JasperBlues doesn't that line above from my Java Configuration cause it to use AspectJ weaving for the Transactional annotation? The txnMgr being passed is the usual JpaTransactionManager. Nothing special there.

Comment: No, I don't think so. To turn on AspectJ you also need to do either 1) Compile-time weaving - Ant/Maven/Cmd-line/IDE task or 2) Runtime weaving - requires a special argument to the JVM -javaagent pointing at the AspectJ jar file.

Comment: @JasperBlues, I'm definitely using AJC and using CTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you loaded your parent entity in the scope of the very transaction where you try to load the lazy children? If it was passed in as parameter for example (that is, loaded from outside your `@Transactional` method) then it might not be bound to a persistence context anymore...

Note that when no `@Transactional` context is given, any database-related action may have a short tx to be created, then immediately closed - disabling subsequent lazy-loading calls. It depends on your [persistence context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547817/what-is-the-difference-between-transaction-scoped-persistence-context-and-extend) and [auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453782/why-set-autocommit-to-true) configurations.

To put it simply, the behaviour with no transactional context being sometimes unexpected, the ground rule is to always have one. If you access your database, then you give yourself a well-defined tx - period. With spring-tx, it means all your `@Repository`'s and `@Service`s are `@Transactional`. This way you should avoid most of tx-related issues.