# Data is not getting submitted in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

CONNECTION FILE

```
package hashconnect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class dbconnect {
    public static Connection con;
    static {
        try {
            String user = "root";
            String password = "abcde";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hashvideos";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

            if(con!=null)
                System.out.println("Connection is ok");
            else
                System.out.println("Connection is not ok");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

---

Register form submission file

```
String Name=request.getParameter("Name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String password=request.getParameter("password");
String contact=request.getParameter("contact");

Connection con=dbconnect.con;
PreparedStatement pst=
con.prepareStatement("insert into register(Name,email,password,contact) values(?,?,?,?)");
pst.setString(1,Name);
pst.setString(2,email);
pst.setString(3,password);
pst.setString(4,contact);

int i=pst.executeUpdate();
```

Please help me out, i am submitting the data but it is not getting submitted
i have tried everything even i have uninstalled and installed again the appropriate softwares but still not getiing the error please help me out.

Comment: Is your connection set to [auto-commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453782/why-set-autocommit-to-true) the queries? Do you have any errors or is all going good but when it's done there is no data?

Comment: everything is going good but when the form is submitting the data is not getting submitted in database and not even the page is redirecting.